# Configure Avast command-line scanner

Tags: windows, avast

Has anyone been able to setup the Avast command line scanner on windows OS to scan a thumb drive or external drive as soon as its connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to information online, the commandline version is only avilable to users of the Avast! Pro Antivirus and Avast! Internet Security products.

A trial version has ashcmd installed with it's temporary licence (in 2007).

Ashquick which is bundled in the Free version can perform a "quick" scan, but doesn't offer a console line interface. Ashcmd will provide further help information as to it's options.

URL Links:

http://avast.helpmax.net/en/command-line-scanner/using-the-command-line/

https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=160562.0

https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=30790.0

Comment: Thank you. Guess it does not work on free version.

Comment: @Kva If you could check my answer as correct, that would be great.

Comment: That's the tick beside your answer, right? Sorry been absent on here for a long time.

Comment: @Kva You have done it correctly. It ensures other users are aware the solution is described well enough without reading too much into the comments. It also prevents the system from bringing it up every so often as a "question in need of answering".